# Removing Constants from a string

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, char, output

I write a code to remove constants from a strings and return vowels. My code is not working for the string which have numbers of words separated by space. Here is my code:

```
    int T;// integer T denoting the number of test cases. For each test case, we input a string.
cin>>T;
string s;
char arr[10] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
for(int n = 0; n < T; n++){
    cin>>s;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){ 
            if(s[i] == arr[j]){cout<<s[i];}
        }
        if(isspace(s[i])){cout<<"n";}
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Input: wdTSFuI IvfHOSNv ,
Its Correct output is: uI IO ,
My Output is: uI

Comment: Constants or consonants? In any case, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, please extract and provide a [mcve]. Further, spell out your actual question, because formally you're not asking one yet.

Comment: Your issue isn't the algorithm but the kind you take the input: `cin>>s;` It stores only contents until first white space into `s`. ([operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)). You may consider `std::getline()` instead. But be careful: Mixing `o>>` (for input of `T`) and `std::getline()` is yet another thing with pitfalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error is because while entering the input through command line C++ omits the data after space so it reads the data only before the space that's why you are getting the vowels present only in the first half.

Three ways to over come this error.

1. to use getline to read the string with spaces the new altered code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;// integer T denoting the number of test cases. For each test case, we input a string.
    cin>>T;
    string s;
    char arr[10] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    for(int n = 0; n < T; n++){
        getline(cin,s);     
        for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){ 
                if(s[i] == arr[j]){
                    cout<<s[i];
                }
            }
            if(isspace(s[i])){cout<<"n";}
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

2. Use Character array to overcome this error.
3. Or provide the input without spaces.

I think this might solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Aravind, I also try this code but it is not responding for multiple test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the solution is to use `std::getline` to read a complete line, including spaces.

I do not understand your line `if(isspace(s[i])){cout<<"n";}`, because in your shown example for output, you want to show the spaces and not a "n". I guess it is a typo and should mean " ".

Anyway. With the use of `std::getline` your function will look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // We need to operate on a given number of test cases
    size_t numberOfTestCases{}; std::cin >> numberOfTestCases;

    // Handle all test cases
    while (numberOfTestCases--) {

        // Read a complete line with text
        std::string line{}; std::getline(std::cin, line);

        // In case of space or vowel, print that
        for (const char c : line)
            if ((c == 32) or ((0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1)) std::cout << c;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And because I see something with "testcases", I guess that you are on some of these unsacred "competition programming" sites.

And thats why I use the condition `((0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1)` to check, if a character is a vowel. This know how is decades old. And adequate for such sites.

If somebody is interested how this works, then please comment and I will edit the answer and explain it.

---

**Edit**

On request, I will explain the for loop. First, we have a so caleed range based for loop. It is the same as writing:

```
for (int i=0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
    const char c = line[i];
    . . .
}
```

Then you can see, that we first check, if the character c is equal to 32. 32 ist the ASCII code for a space. You can see this [here](https://www.virtualuniversity.ch/software/ascii/).

---

So, now, how to check, if a character is a vowel.

If we use the ASCII code to encode letters, then we will see the following:

[image: Ascci Code for Letters]

We see that the ASCII code for uppercase and lowercase letters just differ in the lower 5 bits.

So, if we mask the ASCII code with 0x1F, so `char c{'a'}; unsigned int x{c & 0x1F}`, we will get values between 1 and 26.

So, we can calculte a 5 bit value for each letter.

If we now mark all vowels with a 1, we can build a binary number, consisting of 32bits (an unsigned int) and set a bit at each position, where the vowel is true. We then get something like

```
Bit position
3322 2222 2222 1111 1111 1100 0000 0000  
1098 7654 3210 9876 5432 1098 7654 3210  
Position with vowels:
0000 0000 0010 0000 1000 0010 0010 0010
```

This numer can be converted to 0x208222.

And if we now want to find out, if a letter (regardless whether upper- or lowercase) is a vowel, then we mask out the not necessary bits from the chararcter ( C & 1F ) and shift the binary number to the right as much positions, as the resulting letter code has. If then the bit is set at the LSB position, then we have a vowel. This know how is decades old.

Example: character 'e'. ASCII code is 101. Masking with 1F will make it 5. Then we shift the number 0x208222 (equal to `0000 0000 0010 0000 1000 0010 0010 0010`) these 5 positions to the right, we get `0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0100 0001 0001`. And the lowest bit, with the mark for 'e' is set. Hence, it is a vowel.

Aha. Not so easy, but will work for ASCII coded letters.

By the way, it would also work for other selections of characters.

the result is :

```
auto isVowel = [](char c) { return (0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1; };
```

Cool . . .

Comment: Thanks Armin, Would you please explain the FOR LOOP part of your code so that I can understand.

Comment: @Tanya: I added the explanation. Sorry for late . . .